# Access Elements in SVG with Openlayers 3 using forEachFeatureAtPixel()

Tags: javascript, openlayers, svg

I am trying to access elements (id, style) of a SVG image in Openlayers 3. I tried to link different examples, but the problem is that displaying a SVG is only possible with ImageStatic() and the SVG properties get lost. I am using forEachFeatureAtPixel() to react to different mouse events, which worked fine for a KML layer. How can I access the SVG content with forEachFeatureAtPixel()? A minimum working example is given below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Static Image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var extent = [0, 0, 441, 591];
      var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'static-image',
        units: 'pixels',
        extent: extent
      });

      var topo = new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
              url: 'imgs/example.svg',
              projection: projection,
              imageExtent: extent
            })
          });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [topo],
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: projection,
          center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

      //default for KML
      var changeCursor = function(pixel,evt) {
        var features = [];
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
          alert('works'); //does not show up
          features.push(feature);
        });
        if (features.length > 0) {
          var info = [];
          var i, ii;
          for (i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
            info.push(features[i].get('name'));
          }
          map.getTarget().style.cursor = 'pointer';
        } else {
          //map.getTarget().style.cursor = '';
        }

      };

      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        changeCursor(pixel,evt);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you want your interface to do?